# Custom My Site Tab shoud have same template like My Site - Organisation Tab or My Site - Overview Tab

Tags: 2010, my-site, custom

I created a custom Tab ("CV") in the My Site Area.

The Link shows to "../my/CV.aspx" - i also created a new Website with the specific directory but i'm trying to get the right template there.

The CV-Tab should look and feel alike the "Organisation" or "Overview"-Tab. 
Currently the Website is loaded and the users is directed outside the My Site-"Enviroment"

Any suggestions how to integrate the Tab into My Site?

Regards,

Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a blog post I wrote about creating custom Pages and linking to them with the tabs.  The sample project included will provide the structure and format needed to look like the other Profile pages like the Organization tab.  http://www.mikeoryszak.com/sharepoint/user-profiles-adding-a-custom-tab-and-page

Comment: Great, could have used this two months ago ;)

Comment: Missed the question back then, or I would have worked through the write up then.  I get lots of questions on this general topic at different events since I typically present on MySites and Social related topics.

Answer (score 0):

The Tab Look and Feel only looks like real tabs.. if you select on tab a whole page is loaded and not just the tab.. so just copy the page and make the customization you need.